# Connection from Visual Studio to SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010

In Visual Studio 2010 I am trying to set up a connection with a SQL Server database with the `add connection` wizard but the connection fails!

This is the error I get:

> a network-related or instance-specific error occured while establishing a connection to SQL server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider:Named Pipes Provider, error:40 -Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Extra info;

- I can ping the server!
- Remote connections are allowed on the SQL Server!
- SQL service is running!

What is here the problem?

Comment: Do you use multiple sql server instances on your server? If so, you need to set the server name correctly

Comment: What have you tried? Have you quit Visual Studio and restarted to try the connection again? Are you sure that you are using the right server name?

Comment: Can you connect to the server using sql server management studio? Did you use exactly this server name to connect in your connection manager?

Comment: absolutely, i tried the ip address to, and yes i restarted several times visual studio and SQL server.I checked the properties of my SQL server and remote connections are allowed. How many or wich services should run on the SQL server and Visual Studio?

Comment: What Data Source/Data Provider are you using?

Comment: I just tried to connect through sql mngmt studio and it works, but in the authentication popup, is the server name like this <servername>\SQLEXPRESS

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server (sqlclient)

Comment: Did you try to put `<servername>\SQLEXPRESS` in the connection wizard?

Comment: yes than follows an error like "Login failed for user". The user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection"

Comment: See this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/889615 that will solve your problem.

Comment: OK, problem resolved !! Thanks Pablo for your support!!!

Comment: I will put it in an answer ok?

Answer (score 0):

To work around this problem, use one of the following methods depending on the symptom that you are experiencing:

- **A SQL Server login**

Use a valid Windows login to connect to SQL Server. If you must continue to use a SQL Server login, you can change the security authentication mode in SQL Server to SQL Server and Windows.

- **A Windows account with insufficient permissions**

To work around this problem, you must add the Windows account to SQL Server, and then grant the appropriate permissions to each database that the user requires access to.

Source:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/889615/en-us